# Проблема с окнами Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Работал в Eclipse, свернул нечаянно окно где код, и обратно не как не восстановить. Нажимаю на значок развернуть окно - значок меняется а результата нет.

может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? как мне быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если переключится с Java на C/C+ - все норм, если обратно  -  то что на скрине

Comment: Уже даже подумываю Windows менять